# Is this view done correctly?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-rest-framework

I was going to create view for URL:`url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/objects$', views.UserObject)` to create, update, delete or display object of the user. Furthemore, every user can have only one object. I would be grateful whether you could take a look and tell me if it is done correctly.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def UserObject(request, user_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        try:
            Object.objects.get(user=user_id)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        except Object.DoesNotExist:
            serializer = ObjectSerializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.fields['user'].required = False
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save(user_id=user_id)
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    try:
      object = Object.objects.get(user=user_id)
    except Object.DoesNotExist:
      return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
      serializer = ObjectSerializer(object)
      return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = ObjectSerializer(object, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        object.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**UPDATE**
views.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

    class ObjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Object.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/objects$', views.ObjectViewSet),
```

Comment: so what you need actually? and what is the problem that you are facing now??

Comment: I just would like to know whether it is done correctly. I mean mainly about POST.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [View sets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) are for..

> The ModelViewSet class inherits from GenericAPIView and includes implementations for various actions, by mixing in the behavior of the various mixin classes.

There doesn't look to be much special logic here so

```
class ObjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Object.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
```

looks like all you need

Comment: But my view is done incorrectly? I mean mainly POST.

Comment: @BlueSky - It just seems a bit over complicated for something you could do in 3 lines of code, its unclear what you think is incorrect about your current approach

Comment: So my URL should looks in this way `url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/objects$', views.ObjectViewSet),`?

Comment: I added my solution to the first post. It doesn't work. Any suggestions?